# How to pass a variable to a control from JQuery without posting

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

What I'm trying to do is pass a variable from a jquery script (in this case an id) back to a control (myControl.ascx) embedded in another ascx file. In this case, "myControl.ascx" is hidden until I pass a valid id.

So my control is embedded and called using an id:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <% Html.RenderPartial("myControl.ascx", new MyModel { Id = 1 }); %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I then hit a jquery function:

```
$("#aDropDownID").change(function () {
  var thisid = $("#aDropDownID :selected").val();
  ....
});
```

And that is as far as I've got.  What I want is to pass 'id' back to myControl and set `{ Id = thisid }`.  Obviously not using this syntax but somehow passing the variable back from jquery to a control so that it can render.

If I need to post to a controller using an ajax request ($.ajax) and pass it back then OK but I was hoping for a shortcut without writing excessive code.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: javascript and server code run at different times in different environments. Not clear at all what your expectations are

Comment: You can pass the value to a controller that returns a partial view using `$('#myElement).load('@Url.Action("yourAction", "yourController")', { ID: $(this).val() });` which will replace the contents of the element with the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

Please use like below

```
$("#aDropDownID").change(function () {
   var loc = '@Url.Action("acitonMethodName", new { parameterName = Value })';
   window.location = loc;
});
```